# Can we automate ios apps using appium from windows machine like for android apps?

Tags: appium

Can we automate ios apps using appium from windows machine like for android apps?

Like eclipse and appium is installed on windows machine can we automate ios apps from windows machine instead of doing setup on mac machine?

Comment: Nope, AFAIK you will need xcode and a mac.

Comment: you cannot because appium for iOS use some native libraries, instruments and xcode  of  mac to work